# Is $B$ an open set?

Tags: general-topology

A topology says: '' $A$ is open $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall a\in A-\left \{ 1 \right \}$ ... or $A=\emptyset$ ''

Is $B=\left \{ 1 \right \}$ open?

I can't pick a point of $B$, so it cannot be open, right?

Thanks

Comment: What does the "..." contain?

Comment: Yes, $B$ is open vacuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any statement of the form $\forall_{x \in A} \phi(x)$ is true when $A = \emptyset$. This is called [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

In your case $B\setminus\{1\} = \emptyset$ so you're indeed quantifying over the empty set, making the condition true, and so $B= \{1\}$ is open.